# Cocos2d CCSprite animation fails to load

Tags: animation, cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite, ccspritebatchnode

I am having a weird Cocos2d animation issue.

On init  if my createAndRunAnimationonSprite method  is called works perfectly.

But if I wait and assign it to a button with a method showSprite, the sprite never shows up. I am at a loss as to why this behavior is happening. I have no other methods or classes.

HelloWorldLayer.h

```
@interface AnimationViewerLayer : CCLayer
{
    CCSprite *sprite;

}
```

HelloWorldLayer.m

```
-(id) init
{
    // always call "super" init
    // Apple recommends to re-assign "self" with the "super" return value
    if( (self=[super init])) {

        CGSize winSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
        // initialize the sprite
        sprite = [CCSprite node];
        sprite.position =  ccp( winSize.width/2 , winSize.height/2 );
        [self addChild: sprite];

        // If this is uncommented the sprite will show up. 
        // [self createAndRunAnimationOnSprite];

    }
    return self;
}


-   (void) showSprite { 
       [self createAndRunAnimationOnSprite];
}

-(void) createAndRunAnimationOnSprite {
    // stop all previous ones
    [sprite stopAllActions];
    NSLog(@"Create and Run Animation");
    CGSize winSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;

    [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"ThisSprite.plist"];
    CCSpriteBatchNode *spriteSheet = [CCSpriteBatchNode  batchNodeWithFile:@"ThisSprite.png"];
    [self addChild:spriteSheet];

    NSMutableArray *aniFrames = [NSMutableArray array];
    for(int i = 1; i <= 3; ++i) {
        [aniFrames addObject: [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ThisSprite_walking_%d.png", i]]];
    }

    CCAnimation *walkAnim = [CCAnimation animationWithFrames:aniFrames delay:0.1f];


    sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"ThisSprite_walking_1.png"];
    sprite.position = ccp(winSize.width/2, winSize.height/2);
    id walkAction = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:[CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:walkAnim restoreOriginalFrame:NO]];
    [sprite runAction:walkAction];
    [spriteSheet addChild:sprite];


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're adding the sprite twice. In init you add it to self, in createAndRunAnimation you add it to spriteSheet. This should normally cause an assertion and abort execution of the app (exception).

Comment: Even after removing [self addChild: sprite];, the issue remains the same. During init I can call createAndRunAnimationOnSprite and the spirte appears, but not after.

Comment: Any other guidance? I'm really pulling my hair out.  @LearnCocos2D

Answer (score 0):

There may be a possibility that there is something wrong with your image, either your image name is not accurate or your image is corrupt.

Use some other dummy images to run animation and also try to make a sprite with any of your animation frame i.e. "ThisSprite_walking_1.png" and then see if it works or not

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with this i hope this will work

-(id) init
{

```
    //always call "super" init
    // Apple recommends to re-assign "self" with the "super" return value
    if( (self=[super init])) {

        CGSize winSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
        // initialize the sprite

        [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"ThisSprite.plist"];
        CCSpriteBatchNode *spriteSheet = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"ThisSprite.png"];
        [self addChild:spriteSheet];
        sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"ThisSprite_walking_1.png"];
        sprite.position = ccp(winSize.width/2, winSize.height/2);
        [spriteSheet addChild: sprite];

        // If this is uncommented the sprite will show up. 
         //[self createAndRunAnimationOnSprite];

    }
    return self;
```

}

-(void) createAndRunAnimationOnSprite 
{

```
    // stop all previous ones
    [sprite stopAllActions];
    NSLog(@"Create and Run Animation");
    CGSize winSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;

    NSMutableArray *aniFrames = [NSMutableArray array];
    for(int i = 1; i <= 3; ++i) 
    {
        [aniFrames addObject: [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ThisSprite_walking_%d.png", i]]];
    }

    CCAnimation *walkAnim = [CCAnimation animationWithFrames:aniFrames delay:0.1f];


    id walkAction = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:[CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:walkAnim restoreOriginalFrame:NO]];
    [sprite runAction:walkAction];


}
```